# Show SpecificPriceRule information

Tags: prestashop

I need to show the specific price percentage rule for a group on my Prestashop website but I can't find the class for it. I can show the discounted percentage of a group with the code:

```
{if $customer.is_logged}
        {*$customerGroups|@print_r*}
        {if Group::getCurrent()->reduction}
            <p class="discount"></i> Discount: {Group::getCurrent()->reduction|string_format:"%d"}%</p>
        {/if}
{/if}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all it would be better to move this logic into module and use some kind of custom hook or widget. View is not a place for this kind of things.

You can retrieve any `SpecificPrice` you want using this method:

`SpecificPrice::getSpecificPrice`

So, basically you can hook into `displayProductAdditionalInformation` and do something like:

```
$specificPrice = SpecificPrice::getSpecificPrice(
$this->context->controller->getProduct()->id,
$this->context->shop->id,
$this->context->currency->id,
$ID_OF_THE_GROUP
);

dump($specificPrice);
```

and see what you got :)